# Нужно чтоб .button вместе с .li меняли задний план у меня не выходит помогите пожалуйста

Tags: css, html5

```css
:root {
  --gray: #e4e4e4;
  --lightgray: #F6F6F6;
}


/*SIDEBAR*/

.SideBar {
  width: 360px;
  height: 560px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  margin-left: 195px;
  background-color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.INsideBar {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.SidebarItems {
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: var(--lightgray);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.SidebarItems:hover {
  background-color: var(--lightgray);
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus,
:active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

html,
body {
  max-width: 1920px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: var(--gray);
}

button {
  /* Сбрасываем дефолтные стили */
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="SideBar">
    <ul class="INsideBar">
      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
 <img src="SVG/GROUP1.svg" >
Новини
</button>
      </li>


      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group2.svg" >
      Події міста
    </button>

      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group3.svg" >
  Веб-камери
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group4.svg" >
  Екскурсії та розваги
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/group5.svg" >
  Транспорт Кам’янця
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group6.svg" >
  Де перекусити
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group7.svg" >
  Де зупинитись
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
 <img src="SVG/Group8.svg" >
  Навчальні заклади
</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <body/>
```

Comment: Если запустить пример и повозить мышкой по словам - фон меняется...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменяйте стили button при наведении на li, а чтобы анимация была плавной при наведении и после, добавьте свойство `transition: background 0.5s ease` классам SidebarItems и button:

```css
:root {
  --gray: #e4e4e4;
  --lightgray: #F6F6F6;
}


/*SIDEBAR*/

.SideBar {
  width: 360px;
  height: 560px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  margin-left: 195px;
  background-color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.INsideBar {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.SidebarItems {
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.SidebarItems:hover, .SidebarItems:hover .button { /*При наведении на li меняются стили у li и у button*/
  background-color: var(--lightgray);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus,
:active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

html,
body {
  max-width: 1920px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: var(--gray);
}

button {
  /* Сбрасываем дефолтные стили */
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="SideBar">
    <ul class="INsideBar">
      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
 <img src="SVG/GROUP1.svg" >
Новини
</button>
      </li>


      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group2.svg" >
      Події міста
    </button>

      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group3.svg" >
  Веб-камери
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group4.svg" >
  Екскурсії та розваги
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/group5.svg" >
  Транспорт Кам’янця
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group6.svg" >
  Де перекусити
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
<img src="SVG/Group7.svg" >
  Де зупинитись
</button>
      </li>

      <li class="SidebarItems">
        <button class="button">
 <img src="SVG/Group8.svg" >
  Навчальні заклади
</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <body/>
```